# how to run clearpaht_husky simulation in gazebo?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

is there any way to run ros stacks of clearpath_husky in gazebo?

I want to know, is it possible to simulate clearpath_husky in gazebo without having real-model attached to computer? I want to use it for research purpose, so if it is possible please post how it is possible..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2391/how-to-run-clearpaht_husky-simulation-in-gazebo?/) by [ramaashare](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/288/ramaashare/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

It should be possible to run the husky in Gazebo.

Google told me:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/husky_simulator

http://www.ros.org/wiki/husky_simulator

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0